# How do you interpret 'have' in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It is very important to have invoices signed by two on-site managers.

In the above sentence, do you interpret 'have' as 'ownership' or 'make'?

In other words,

1. It is very important to have invoices that are signed by two on-site managers.
2. It is very important to let invoices signed by two on-site managers.

What interpretation is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While it is technically ambiguous.  The natural interpretation is the "cause to happen" meaning of "have someone do something".  You could rephrase this without the passive as:

> It is very important to have two on-site managers sign invoices.